# Dune 2 Legacy - difficulty

Tags: dune-2

I am playing the campaign of Dune Legacy v. 0.96.4, but I have problem with the difficulty. First time I started without changing any settings and couldn't pass the 5th mission. I switched the difficulty in options to easy (qBot Easy), but now I can't pass over the 7th mission since it is too hard. Are there options to get back to original difficulty? Or can I modify qBot?

Comment: I am playing again after 2+ years... Same operating system, Dune Legacy version, different source files but after first start BEFORE start champain i was set difficulty to qBot easy and i have complete whole harconen campain without any problems... So maybe you cannot change difficulty in 'open' campain... Maybe this is the magic...